# Hibernate assigns null values to columns during insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

**Warehouse.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "warehouses")
public class Warehouse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "is_default")
    private boolean isDefault;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "warehouse", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private WarehouseAddress address;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "warehouses")
    private Store store;

    //other getters and setters

    public WarehouseAddress getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(WarehouseAddress address) {
        this.address = address;
        this.address.setWarehouse(this);
    }

    //equals hashCode
}
```

**WarehouseAddress.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "warehouse_addresses")
public class WarehouseAddress {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "warehouse_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Warehouse warehouse;

    @Column(name = "street_name")
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "street_number")
    private String streetNumber;

    @Column(name = "floor")
    private String floor;

    @Column(name = "door_number")
    private String doorNumber;

    @Column(name = "observation")
    private String observation;

    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "warehouse_addresses")
    private Province province;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "code", table = "warehouse_addresses")
    private Country country;

    //other getters and setters

    public void setWarehouse(Warehouse warehouse) {
        this.warehouse = warehouse;
    }

    //equals and hashCode
}
```

The problem I'm getting is that whenever I have a `Warehouse` entity that doesn't have a `WarehouseAddress`, and I attempt to create one manually as shown in the self contained example below, I get the following exception:

```
2021-06-08 14:50:51,456 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL: insert into warehouse_addresses (city, country_code, door_number, floor, observation, province_id, street_name, street_number, zip_code, warehouse_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-06-08 14:50:51,461 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2021-06-08 14:50:51,461 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Column 'city' cannot be null
2021-06-08 14:50:51,467 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'city' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at ...
```

This is a quick and dirty example that triggers the following exception:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {

    private ProvinceService provinceService;
    private CountryService countryService;
    private WarehouseService warehouseService;
    private StoreService storeService;
    private WarehouseRepository warehouseRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(ProvinceService provinceService, CountryService countryService, WarehouseService warehouseService, StoreService storeService, WarehouseRepository warehouseRepository) {
        this.provinceService = provinceService;
        this.countryService = countryService;
        this.warehouseService = warehouseService;
        this.storeService = storeService;
        this.warehouseRepository = warehouseRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @Transactional
    public void test() {
        Store store = storeService.findById(55);
        Warehouse warehouse = warehouseService.findByNameAndStore("WarehouseTestName", store);
        WarehouseAddress newAddress = new WarehouseAddress();
        warehouse.setAddress(newAddress);
        newAddress.setProvince(provinceService.findByCode("AR-C"));
        newAddress.setCountry(countryService.findByCode("AR"));
        newAddress.setStreetName("a");
        newAddress.setStreetNumber("a");
        newAddress.setFloor(null);
        newAddress.setDoorNumber(null);
        newAddress.setObservation(null);
        newAddress.setZipCode("155");
        newAddress.setCity("CABA");

        warehouseRepository.save(warehouse);
    }
}
```

**Interesting things I found**

- If I move `warehouse.setAddress(newAddress);` to be called after
  `newAddress.setCity("CABA");` I don't get the exception.
- Hibernate seems to "magically" populate the `id` field in `WarehouseAddress` after calling `newAddress.setProvince(provinceService.findByCode("AR-C"));`, which is even weirder. This doesn't happen if I do what I mentioned earlier and call `setAddress` after setting the address fields.

Any help would be appreciated as to what could be causing this issue. I sadly can't use the first workaround because I'm using MapStruct to update DB entities and the generated code first assigns the `WarehouseAddress` to the `Warehouse` and then maps its properties (like in the example).

Comment: does `provinceService.findByCode("AR-C")` perform a call to the database? Why I am asking: Hibernate automatically flushes entities **before** performing a read operation to avoid dirty reads.

Comment: @DanielWosch Yes, it calls the repository like this: `provinceRepository.findByCode(provinceCode);` If what you're saying is true, is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Then please see my updated comment: You need to perform the get first before updating the Warehouse entity. Otherwise all changes before your read operation are flushed to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `warehouse.setAddress(newAddress);` **first** you modify the managed entity (*managed entity because you have fetched the warehouse from the database => now managed by hibernate*). After that you are performing a query operation => Hibernate flushes your previous changes to the database to prevent dirty reads before performing the database query operation. In this case the properties of `newAddress` are not set which leads to the constraint violation exception. Same goes for the

> Hibernate seems to "magically" populate the id field in
> WarehouseAddress after calling
> newAddress.setProvince(provinceService.findByCode("AR-C"));,

The `WarehouseAddress` gets persisted before performing the query operation and has therefore an id.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I shall open a ticket with MapStruct to see if they can alter the order of assignment.

Comment: How does your code with map struct looks? Maybe there is a possibility to adjust it?

Comment: My Mapstruct usage is as specified in their manual, the problem lies in the generated code that results from my mappings (can't edit it). I will leave the GitHub ticket I created here where I go into detail about my mappings and the generated code:
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2475

Comment: One hack would be to implement a default method in MapStruct Mapping interface which first maps the address and then performs the set operation as your posted at GitHub.

Comment: I seem to have found a workaround that will have to do for now, at least until they take action. https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2475#issuecomment-857037504